# Interpolating values using What If Paramter as input

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of the following format:

[image]

I have a what if parameter in a slicer where the user can input a year. I want to use this value to return the interpolated Discount Factor for each of the different Curves.

```
Spot Rate (Lookup) = 
    VAR DurationFloor = FLOOR([Duration Value] * 12,1)
    VAR DurationCeiling = CEILING([Duration Value] * 12,1)

    VAR DiscountFloor = CALCULATE(MAX(facYieldCurves[Discount Factor]),facYieldCurves[Month] = DurationFloor)
    VAR DiscountCeiling = CALCULATE(MAX(facYieldCurves[Discount Factor]),facYieldCurves[Month] = DurationCeiling)

    Return
    ([Duration] - DurationFloor) * (DiscountCeiling - DiscountFloor) + DiscountFloor
```

This code doesn't appear to work and takes a long time to refresh.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your issue is. Please can you expand along with your expected results?

Comment: Two issues 1) Query returns the wrong values, 2) Takes a very long time to run

Answer (score 0):

Reworked my code and now works:

```
Discount Rate (Lookup) = 

VAR DurationFloor = FLOOR('Duration'[Duration Value]*12,1)
VAR DurationCeiling = CEILING('Duration'[Duration Value]*12,1)
VAR DiscountFloor = CALCULATE(MAX(facYieldCurves[Discount Factor]),FILTER(facYieldCurves, [Month] = DurationFloor))
VAR DiscountCeiling = CALCULATE(MAX(facYieldCurves[Discount Factor]),FILTER(facYieldCurves, [Month] = DurationCeiling))

RETURN
    IF(
        DurationFloor = DurationCeiling,
        DiscountFloor,
        DiscountFloor + (DiscountCeiling - DiscountFloor) / (DurationCeiling - DurationFloor) * ('Duration'[Duration Value]*12 - DurationFloor)
    )
```